# Execute function in Iframe from parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

Impossible to execute function in Iframe from Parent without the sandbox : allow-same-origin. (when I put it, it works)

But I need to avoid this for the security of my modul.

> Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame

The domain, port and protocol are the same. Only the path to file is different

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server side language skills, you can scrape the url that you want to post to and deliver it locally. Some would call this a router page.

So, myrouter.php receives $_POST['url'], php validates the url through a hash or some other means, then delivers the content to your app. Now you are able to post into the container. Otherwise, and I just digested the rest of your problem, you could use a server side include and "Bam", problem solved.